# Why does Angular default to placing application routing into its own module?

Tags: angular

The Angular documentation and Angular CLI push the Angular beginner (I'm in this boat) to implement application routing in a separate module from the main application, without really explaining why it gets this special treatment.  For example, when I scaffold a new Angular project with routing using the CLI, I get a `app-routing.module.ts` file when is imported in my main `app.module.ts` file.

I have read the it's because of Separation of Concerns, but I have a hard time accepting this as the entire reason, because there are multiple concerns in an application, yet only routing is gets its own module.

As a beginner in Angular, I have no idea if this is an opinion based question, or there is a legitimate technical reason why it's a good idea.  I can't find any information one way or the other, which is why I'm asking.

For those Angular veterens who have worked on medium-largish applications, when do you put or not put your application routing in a separte module, and why?  Does it become technically necessary at a certain point, or is this simply a organizational convention?

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of folks *don't* understand voting and accepting, or why they're important ;)  If you're asking specifically about why `app-routing.module.ts` exists, and why it needs to be implemented as a separate module - it doesn't.  A lot of my projects simply have an `app\app-routes.ts`.  It *imports* `{ Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`, but it doesn't have its own `@NgModule({...});`.

Comment: it's now re-opened :)  I believe this is your question, regarding the auto-generated module "app-routing.module.ts": `When do you put or not put your application routing in a separate module, and why? Does it become technically necessary at a certain point, or is this simply a organizational convention?`  My vote is "organizational convention" ... but I'm prepared to be wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's all about separation of concerns. While you may be tempted to but the entire app logic in a single module, it's usually recommended to separate each concern to a separate module. A module defining views that display product info, should not worry directly how and when its views are rendered. Decoupling different logic areas from each other, will make your code cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your ansewr EmmBee.  I understand the principle of separation of concerns, but I'm left feeling like that can't be the whole answer.  For example, I would say an application's Services are a different concern than the view, yet they don't get their own module like routing does.  Or am I missing something?  Could a reason be that routes are defined in their own module because Angular routes could potentially span/point-to multiple modules?

Comment: Services *should* be separate units.  Those "units" just don't happen to be an Angular "module".  Here's a good definition: `a module is a mechanism to group components, directives, pipes and services that are related, in such a way that can be combined with other modules to create an application. An Angular application can be thought of as a puzzle where each piece (or each module) is needed to be able to see the full picture.`: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/modules/introduction